# From which version Mathematica will be available Symbolic n-th derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

On [www.wolframalfa.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D[exp[-x%5E2*%281-x%29],%7Bx,n%7D]) Symbolic n-th derivative works.

> ---

[image]

**Edited:**

On new version Mathematica 11.1 symbolic n-th derivative works.

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7886/5478

Comment: Use `SeriesCoefficient[]` with an appropriate correction factor instead.

Comment: @J.M. and Seeing your comments you do not know which version of MMA will be.I think that in the next 10.5 or 11. Calculation made by WolframAlfa, are incorrect.Bug in WolframAlfa Engine. :)

Comment: related: [(9598)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9598/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think currently the selected duplicate isn't proper, this question is more of a duplicate of the one you linked, and just related to the one selected as the duplicate at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```
D[f[x],{x,n}]
```

To get the n-th derivative for x.

EDIT:
Ah sorry now i get what you asked for. You want that Mathematica gives you the sum in your screenshoot.

Comment: You can delete own questions if you want.